# how to use searchfilters and viewbase in microsoft exchange web service (EWS)

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, searchfiltercollection

I'm reading emails from exchange server using Exchange web service(EWS).
I want to read emails from exchange server having `DateTimeSent`  greater than `datetime.now`.
I haven't used `searchfilter` and viewbase which are parameters of `FindItems`, how to use them?

```
       //Email exchange starts here
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1)
    {
        Credentials = new WebCredentials(credentials.SmtpUser, credentials.SmtpPassword)
    };

    //to add logic for itemview
    service.AutodiscoverUrl(credentials.SmtpFromAddress, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
    //var inbox = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(100));
      var inbox = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,); //what to add here?

    foreach (EmailMessage item in inbox.Items.Where(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.DateTimeSent) > dateTime.Now))
    {

    }
```

Comment: `DateTimeSent` greater than `DateTime.Now` - how can it happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea how `DateTimeSent` can be greater than `DateTime.Now` and why would you need it, but the following is a sample how can you perform the search:

```
string email = "<user>@<host>";
string user = "<user>";
string password = "<password>";
string serviceUrl = "https://<url>/ews/exchange.asmx";

Mailbox mailbox = new Mailbox(email);
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(user, password);
service.Url = new Uri(serviceUrl);

FolderId inbox = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, mailbox);
SearchFilter searchFilter = new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThan(ItemSchema.DateTimeSent, DateTime.Now);
ItemView view = new ItemView(10); // take 10 items
view.OrderBy.Add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, SortDirection.Descending);
FindItemsResults<Item> result = service.FindItems(inbox, searchFilter, view);
```

Comment: sorry i wrote datetime.Now as an example i'm using another date. Thanks ulugbek